# Unable to remove elements from Map's entry set

Tags: java, dictionary

Here is my program

```
   public class MapTest{


   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Map<String, Integer> m = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
   m.put("John", 1);
   m.put("Mary", 2);
   m.put("Edward", 3);

   for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : m.entrySet())
   {

   e.remove();  //This line gives error.
   System.out.println(e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue());
   }
   System.out.println("actual key "+m);

    }
    }
```

According to java docs [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)

> The Collection views support element removal in all its many forms — remove, removeAll, retainAll, and clear operations, as well as the Iterator.remove operation. (Yet again, this assumes that the backing Map supports element removal.)

**Here the backing Map supports element removal.So how come I am unable to remove the element?**

Comment: You should read the [`javadoc`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Comment: @Sotirios Could you tell me which line?

Comment: What do you mean which line? When you don't know the methods that a class provides, you read its javadoc. The link above is the `Map` class' javadoc. You can follow through and check the `Map.Entry` class. If you read it carefully, you'll notice `Entry` doesn't have a `remove()` method.

Comment: Use m.remove(e.getKey())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work that way, try this

```
    for (Iterator<Entry<String, Integer>> i = m.entrySet().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        Entry<String, Integer> e = i.next();
        i.remove();
        System.out.println(e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue());
    }
```

Map.remove with no args does not exist, you can try m.remove(e.getKey()) but then you will be getting ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: @Evgenify and Sotirios I know I can delete elements via `i.remove()` but I wanna know why I am unable to remove it via my program

Comment: @TruePS Because that method doesn't exist.

Comment: @Sotirios So why Java Docs say e Collection views support element removal in all its many forms — remove, removeAll, retainAll, and clear operations, as well as the Iterator.remove operation. (Yet again, this assumes that the backing Map supports element removal.)

Comment: @TruePS `Entry` is not a `Collection`. A `Set` is a `Collection`.